# bcrypt generate salt function

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

I had the following in my code when I first created my hashed password using Bcrypt.

```
let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.formdata.password, 10);
```

And then I changed created a function to do the hashing and I did the following:

```
let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
let hashedValue = bcrypt.hashSync(value, salt);
return hashedValue;
```

Now when I do a Bcrypt.compare for some, not all existing users, I get a self generated message that the passwords don't match.  My question is does both these methods of hashing, create different hashed passwords that now it won't match when I do a compare?